# Prove the alternating sequence diverges

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that the sequence diverges:

$x_{n}$= {1 if $n$ is odd,
       $0$ if $n$ is even}

What I have:

Let $\epsilon$ > $0$ be given. We require that each element of  $x_{n}$ > $\epsilon$   $\forall n>N$.

Comment: I guess you must prove that the sequence does not converge.

Comment: Yes. That is it.

Comment: Have you done any examples where you prove some sequence is not convergent or this is the first one such...

Comment: No, this is the first one.

Comment: If $(x_n)$ converges to some limit $L$, then eventually (for large enough $n$), all of the elements must in the interval $(L-1/4, L+1/4)$. Can you see why this is impossible?

Comment: Good... So, to prove something is convergent, we start with given $\epsilon$.. We want to prove that it is not convergent to any $L$, so, we are going by contradiction.. So, we should give $\epsilon>0$ such that given any $N\in\mathbb{N}$ there exists some $n>N$ such that $|x_n-L|>\epsilon$...

Comment: Yes. So epsilon must be something like 1\4? Sorry, this seems like an easy question now...

Comment: why do you thing $\frac{1}{4}$ works...  please explain how does that satisfy the conditions that i have said,,,